# Are there any issues with specifying the specific version for maven plugins

Tags: java, maven

I always wondered, are there any issues with specifying versions for maven plugins like surefire or the compiler.

So I am using mvn version 3.5 with java8 and will do an upgrade with mvn 3.8.x with java11+.

I may use the latest plugins with mvn 3.8x but dont know about 3.5.  Is there any issues with doing that.  Doesn't it make sense to not use the version and have the root maven includes add the right versions that are available?

For example.

This is 3.5 and plugin 2.x for surefire.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: This is not opinion-based: the question is "are there any issues with specifying versions for maven plugins?"

Comment: I strongly recommend to define all version of all the plugin you are using within your build in pluginManagement and also using the most recent versions of the plugin... independent of your used Maven version.. apart from that I strongly recommend to use the most recent version of Maven as well...

Comment: To move that away from an opinion... If you don't specify the versions and upgrade of Maven could cause issues based on plugin versions. To get a reproducible build define all versions of all plugins...

Comment: I should have worded my question differently but these are good answers anyway.  Maybe someone could ask again, I dont see this mentioned anywhere.  Only problem I wonder if bad version causes and issue and what version do you pick?

Comment: @BerlinBrown If you picked a version (plugins/maven) which causes issues you should pick the previous version and recheck.. and what would be great to report the issue(https://selfserve.apache.org/jira-account.html) .. and after it's being fixed upgrade...

Comment: BTW: Is there a good reason why not picking up Maven 3.9.X line instead of Maven 3.8.x ?

Comment: No reason, I saw java11 was matched more with 3.8x.  I can use 3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the default versions of maven plugins is not recommended and generates a big warning:

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for test:test:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin is missing. @ line 22, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

You should always specify the version of each plugin and using the latest version is the typical approach.  The [minimum maven version](https://ci-maven.apache.org/job/Maven/job/maven-box/job/maven-dist-tool/job/master/site/dist-tool-prerequisites.html) required by common plugins is very old so you should not have any issue; if any version-compatibility issue arises the build fails so it is evident.

If you use `spring-boot-starter-parent` it defines the latest version of common plugins [for you](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using) and you can easily override any of its defaults if you want.